# Include template by variable

Tags: django

I have a model like this:

```
class Component(models.Model)
    html_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) #example value: header_1.html

class MyModel(models.Model):
    components = models.ManyToManyField(Component ...)
```

In my Django project I have the following structure.

```
root
----myapp
--------templates
------------myapp
----------------templates
--------------------default_template_1.html
----------------components
--------------------header_1.html
```

In my template(default_template_1.html)  I would like to do something like this:

```
{% for applied_component in mymodel.components.all %}
    {% with '../components/'|add:applied_component as component_template %}
        {% include component_template %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

That gives me an error: `TemplateDoesNotExist`. However if I extract that string inside `component_template` and just hardcode it, then the include works fine. So it seems like it's something with the fact that it's a variable.

I also tried changing include to: `{% include component_template|stringformat:"i" %}`
But that gives me:

```
PermissionError at /app/event/1/
[Errno 13]
```

Comment: What happens if you try an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: ^ Solved. Thank you. Not sure why it doesn't work with a relative as a variable though but an absolut path works fine aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a template variable as the include string and for my system it works fine:

```
{% with settings.get_template as template %}
{% if template %}
<div class="setupFormWrapper">
  <form action="{% url 'simple:setup:products:settings_set' selected.id %}" method="POST" id="settingsForm" class="form{{ settings.formClass }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ template }}
  </form>
</div>
```

So what you're trying to do is definitely possible. Are you sure you're constructing the path properly and that the template engine has access / permissions to handle the template?

For findability in google: The answer was to use absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: Thank you, good to know it should work. Couldn't find anyone else who had tried this (maybe because it usually works).